# Truncate HTML to certain number of words

Tags: c#, html, sharepoint-2010, truncate

I have an HTML string and I'm trying to display a given number (n) of words from the HTML. I want to keep the HTML formatting, but only show n number of words.

I've searched high and low but most of the examples just show how to convert HTML to plain text with n number of words. If this is not possible then at least n number of characters and still keep the HTML formatting.

I'm using **c#** within a SharePoint Web Part getting the HTML from a blog post, although doesn't have to relate to SharePoint at all - just any HTML.

Thanks in advance.

Grant.

Answer (score 0):

For any operation like this on HTML, you probably want the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).